# SQL code for delete Row?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

please anyone to explain me what is the problem with following code why didn't delete Table Row.

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from RentTable where CID = '" + ID + "' and MID = '" + MID + "' )", con);
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (result == 1)
{
    Message = "succsess";
}
else
{
    Message = "!";
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show your table definition.  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: could it be that there are no rows meeting the criteria?

Comment: did it say "succsess" and then you found the record still there?

Comment: You should use parameterized queries/statements.  Not string concatenation.  Otherwise you are prone to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your sql appears to have a closing brace in it without having an opening brace.

change it to

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
     "delete from RentTable where CID = '" + ID + "' and MID = '" + MID + "'"
     , con);
```

Answer (score 3):

75% of all these types of problems would be fixed if people loaded their queries into a string variable first then printed them out for debugging purposes :-)

You have a closing parenthesis `)` at the end of your query which shouldn't be there.

Comment: ... and used parameters instead of sew query by concatenation. It isn't even about sql injections, it's about readability!

Answer (score 2):

your command is:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "delete from RentTable where CID = '" + ID + "' and MID = '" + MID + "' )",
    con
);
```

while it should be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "delete from RentTable where CID = '" + ID + "' and MID = '" + MID + "' ", 
    con
);
```

(you should remove the ")"   from your command)

Answer (score 2):

Change row with sql command creation to this:

```
/* look at this - no need to wrap string values with 
   apostrophes since you use parameters */
string query = "delete from RentTable where CID = @id and MID = @mid";

/* create command */
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

/* set parameters */
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mid", MID);
```

This's not only solve your problem. This'll help you to prevent problems like it in the future if you'll be using parameters instead concatenation.

**PS**. Also you have "succsess" misspelled if english word was meant ;)